# How to track a thank you page that doesn't change url with GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I want to add an Application event on GTM, however the page I want to add it to is a SPA. Additionally, when you click through the details of the application, the final page, which is the thank you page, doesn't change the URL, so I can't just make a regular Pageview for it.

I am thinking about using Element Visibility trigger instead of the Pageview, but I am wondering how should I go about this. Can I somehow make it so the tag fires when, for example, the h1 tag containing "Thank you" appears on the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a history change trigger at first.
Try to see there is a new state when thanks you page happened.

Element Visibility is another way,
Need to observe when the "Thanks you" show on the page.
Is there any html element also show on this page.

Take an example
Before transaction happen:

```
<div id="thanksYouText">
    <h1 class="hide"> Thanks you </h1>
</div>
```

After the transaction happed:

```
<div id="thanksYouText">
    <h1 class="show"> Thanks you </h1>
</div>
```

and you can set a Element Visibility Trigger to get the `"div#thanksYouText h1"`
When the element shows, GTM will capture it and fire the tag you set for this trigger.

Comment: Since this is an SPA the "thank you" element is probably displayed via a change in the DOM rather than via CSS, so the OP might have to check the "observe DOM changes" option.

Comment: Hmm i tried these and they didn't work.. Turns out the page was using iframe, so i coudnt really see what was going on. Now that the iframe has gtm installed, i can just go ahead and specify the click text on the "Apply" button and page URL. Thanks for the suggestions.  It is kinda sad that i didnt get the element visibility to work, could have learnt something new.